# why does the addDomain method affect the Domain's SuperClass

Tags: java, jena, owl

the simplest example code works as below.

```
    OntModel individuals = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        TreeMap<String, String> namespaces=new TreeMap<String,String>();
        namespaces.put("pubo", "http://www.example.org.cn/standards/publishing/ontology/cores/");
        individuals.setNsPrefixes(namespaces);
        OntClass class1=individuals.createClass(namespaces.get("pubo")+"class1");
        class1.setLabel("class1", "en");
        OntClass class2=individuals.createClass(namespaces.get("pubo")+"class2");
        class2.setLabel("class2", "en");
class2.setSuperClass(class1);
        System.out.println(class2.getSuperClass().getURI());
        DatatypeProperty p = individuals.createDatatypeProperty(namespaces
                .get("pubo") + "haha");
        p.addDomain(class2);
        System.out.println(class2.getSuperClass().getURI());
```

The first output is:http://www.example.org.cn/standards/publishing/ontology/cores/class1.
After i p.addDomain(class2),the second output is:http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource.
why???? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### [getSuperClass](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#getSuperClass())
>
> ```
> OntClass getSuperClass()
> ```
>
> Answer a class that is the super-class of this class. **If there is more
>   than one such class, an arbitrary selection is made.** If there is no
>   such super-class, return null.

I agree that the behavior is a bit surprising, but it's not *incorrect*.  The documentation says:
Both **class1** and **rdfs:Resource** are superclasses of your **class2**, so both can be legitimately returned by getSuperClass, since all it's guaranteed to "a super-class".  Since what Jena is probably doing internally is asking for *all* the triples of the form **class2 rdfs:subClassOf X** and taking the first value of *X*, all it takes to get a different result is for something to happen that changes values of *X* that could be returned or the order in which they're returned.  In general, that stuff isn't specified, so there's nothing incorrect going on here.

If you want to check whether something is a superclass of another, you can iterate through all the values produced by [listSuperClasses](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#listSuperClasses()), or simply check with [hasSuperClass](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#hasSuperClass(com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource)).  Both of those methods have a variant which accepts a boolean argument, so be sure to check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, yesterday i send a help email to the jena user mail-list, and one guy gave the same suggestion as you did. After i changed the getSupClass to listSupClasses and manually sifted out the rdfs:resource ,my code finally worked.Thank you very much.

Comment: You'll find that a lot of the same people follow the [tag:jena] tag here and read the Jena list.